# Por que em uma extensão de método do tipo genérico eu não preciso explicitar um tipo ao chamá-lo?

Tags: c#, .net, método, genéricos, inferência

No *link* abaixo há um trecho de código que consiste em nada mais do que um método Shuffle que é utilizado como um *Extension Method* de *Array*. Apesar do método ser do tipo genérico, eu não preciso passar um tipo quando o chamo. Por que isso acontece?

Não preciso fazer:

```
var randomDigits = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).ToArray().Shuffle<int>();
```

Basta:

```
var randomDigits = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).ToArray().Shuffle();
```

[Link](https://rextester.com/DUXNT12340).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pergunta deveria ser

> Por que em uma extensão de método do tipo genérico eu não preciso explicitar um tipo ao chamá-lo?

Porque a resposta é justamente a inferência que o compilador faz. O [`Enumarable.Range()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.range?view=net-6.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) produz um tipo enumerável do tipo `int`. E o `ToArray()` concretiza isso (provavelmente de forma desnecessária), mas não muda o tipo. Então `Shuffle()`, que é genérico, pode ser inferido pelo compilador que é um inteiro que está manipulando.

Em muitos casos o compilador está preparado para descobrir o tipo a ser usado, desde que tenha essa informação de forma calara e simples, o que é o caso. Não é diferente do que permite usar o `var`, o compilador consegue identificar que tipo é tudo aquilo e deixar você omitir o tipo.

Nem tudo o compilador pode inferir, e mesmo algumas coisas que parecem que dá pode ser ambíguo, pelo menos para o compilador que nem sempre foi criado para ver certos padrões, aí você teria que explicitar.

Fica melhor não precisar escrever quando é facilmente identificável.

Então entenda que ali é como se usasse o `var`, mas nem isso é preciso escrever.